# How can I know the compatibility of the asp.net packages to .net core without .NET Portability Analyzer or VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, nuget

I have list of nuget packages used in asp.net application I have to migrate the app into .net core. How can I know the compatibility of the packages without .NET Portability Analyzer or VS.
on nuget.org site only packages are shown not their framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Target Framework Monikers (TFMs) that each package supports on nuget.org under the Dependencies section of the package page.

Read more about Analyze your dependencies to port code to .NET Core [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/third-party-deps)